# MYSQL request | Group Dates by year and month

Tags: php, mysql, json

My question is: 
I have a mysql table: events and would like to get special formatted json_string.

```
    id   event
    1    2010-01-01 00:00:00 
    2    2010-07-02 00:00:00 
    3    2011-01-04 00:00:00 
    4    2012-01-30 00:00:00 
    5    2012-03-15 00:00:00 
...
```

I need to get json string:

```
{"events":[
   {"2010":
      {
       "1":{"id":1,"event":2010-01-01 00:00:00},
       "7":{"id":2,"event":2010-07-02 00:00:00}
      },
   },
   {"2011:
      {
       "1":{"id":3,"event":2012-01-30 00:00:00}
      },
   },
   {"2012:
      {
       "1":{"id":4,"event":2011-01-04 00:00:00},
       "3":{"id":5,"event":2012-03-15 00:00:00},
      },
   }
]}
```

My code below:

```
$result = DB::query('SELECT id, event FROM events');
 $events = array();
 while($event = $result->fetch_object()) {
     // the following statement won't get desired results
     $events[] = $event;
 }

 return array(
    'events' => json_encode($events);
 );
```

How do I change my code to get the above JSON string?

Comment: Updated it to form a question :)

Comment: @lanzz: don't think it's too hard to imply "how do I do this?" at the end of the post. If all questions would be posted like this I would be glad.

Comment: @Quassnoi It is not clear what problem the asker is experiencing. This is not a question, this is a mission he's bestowing upon us, should we choose to accept it.

Comment: @lanzz: "I need to get json string" with the exact string following is quite clear to me.

Comment: @Quassnoi He's not explaining what is his problem with producing the required output. He is merely asking us to do his work instead of him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `substr()` the parts you need from the event date and use that to construct a multi-dimensional array:

```
while($event = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $year = substr($event->event, 0, 4);
    $month = (int)substr($event->event, 5, 2);

    $events[$year][$month][] = $event;
}
```

Comment: Your code return just: {"events":{"2012":{"1":{"id":1,"event":"2010-01-01 00:00:00"}}}}

Comment: @user889349 that would be the result for a single row; are you sure that query returns enough results?

Comment: Yes. I have no LIMIT in my query.

Comment: Your solution return last row:{"events":{"2012":{"3":{"id":5,"event":"2012-03-15 00:00:00"}}}}

Comment: This code return all rows: while($event = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $year = substr($event->event, 0, 4);
    //$month = (int)substr($event->event, 5, 2);
    $events[$year][] = $event;
}
But without month. Where can be a problem? Thanks!

Comment: Find the problem: Should be: $events[$year][$month][] = $event; Thanks!

Comment: @user889349 okay, i've updated my answer; from your example I didn't see a need to add the `[]` :) please accept if all is well